# Sound visualization library for Android

Tags: android, android-library

I'm looking for a library that can help me achieve sound visualization.
Ror example, something like this:

[image]

Do you know about any open source / paid library for that?

Comment: Is your problem is solved or not ?

Comment: https://github.com/anandBrose/AmplitudeGraphView-Android This works as you want

Answer (score 16):

I was able to find the following libraries open-sourced on GitHub:

- https://github.com/Cleveroad/WaveInApp
- https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-openslmediaplayer
- https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer
- https://github.com/steelkiwi/AndroidRecording

I just googled "android audio visualizer library". You could try this too.

Comment: I think according to the question, he is looking for some timeline like visualizer where, as audio recording, the graph or visual effect generates like a timeline.