# How do I make column graph visualizer based on frequency (like below) for music playing in Android?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-mediaplayer, android-music-player

[image: Example:]

I have found some answers couldn't understand.

[How to draw waveform of Android's music player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317842/how-to-draw-waveform-of-androids-music-player)

[Android 2.3 Visualizer - Trouble understanding getFft()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720512/android-2-3-visualizer-trouble-understanding-getfft)

Found 4 libraries but all are outdated as well buggy when I tried on my phone:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37688330/6737655

Is there any new library or explanation on how to do it? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: "I have found some answers couldn't understand." What specifically did you not understand?

Comment: The explained on obtaini.g waveform, but I need clomn chart type like in the pic. Should I ise openGl for.this kind of visualization? The libraries given are outdated and don't work in some phones.