# How can i create audio visualizer in android studio?

Tags: java, android, visualization, graph-visualization, visualizer

I am creating sound recording app, and i need to create audio visualizer. I looked at this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688002/sound-visualization-library-for-android), but there was only outdated libraries and i looked at several other questions, but i could not find the answer.

Do you know about any open source github not outdated projects?

I want to make a sound visualization that would look something like below image:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this Library for a visualization of your Audio while recording

https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Voice-Recorder

I have used this in my application, and it's working really well.
It's not outdated, and is up to dated to be used in new projects.
Thanks